# Let $k,l,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k+1\leq n$. Find a general formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^l \dfrac{l\choose i}{n\choose {k+i}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let $k,l,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k+1\leq n$. Find a general formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^l \dfrac{l\choose i}{n\choose {k+i}}$.

I think the formula should involve a fraction and a combination. I tried plugging in values of $i$ but I couldn't get anywhere. Next I tried expanding the combinations, but I got a really nasty expression, so that didn't get me anywhere either. Any hints, preferably major, would be nice.

Comment: Do you mean $k+l\leq n$?

Comment: Hint: after some rearranging, $\binom{l}{i}/\binom{n}{k+i} = \frac{k! l! (n-k-l)!}{n!} \binom{k+i}{k} \binom{n-k-i}{n-k-l}$, and $\sum_{i=0}^l \binom{k+i}{k} \binom{n-k-i}{n-k-l}$ has a nice combinatorial interpretation.